# How to use a class object in C++ as a function parameter

Tags: c++, parameters

I am not sure how to have a function that receives a class object as a parameter. Any help? Here is an example below.

```
#include<iostream>

void function(class object); //prototype

void function(class tempObject)
{
   //do something with object
   //use or change member variables
}
```

Basically I am just confused on how to create a function that will receive a class object as its parameters, and then to use those parameters inside the function such as `tempObject.variable`.

Sorry if this is kind of confusing, I am relatively new to C++.

Comment: @Adrian Please do not invent new tags - there are far too many as it is.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`class` is a keyword that is used only* to introduce class definitions. When you declare new class instances either as local objects or as function parameters you use only the name of the class (which must be in scope) and not the keyword `class` itself.

e.g.

```
class ANewType
{
    // ... details
};
```

This defines a new type called `ANewType` which is a class type.

You can then use this in function declarations:

```
void function(ANewType object);
```

You can then pass objects of type `ANewType` into the function. The object will be *copied* into the function parameter so, much like basic types, any attempt to modify the parameter will modify only the parameter in the function and won't affect the object that was originally passed in.

If you want to modify the object outside the function as indicated by the comments in your function body you would need to take the object by reference (or pointer). E.g.

```
void function(ANewType& object); // object passed by reference
```

This syntax means that any use of `object` in the function body refers to the actual object which was passed into the function and not a copy. All modifications will modify this object and be visible once the function has completed.

[* The `class` keyword is also used in template definitions, but that's a different subject.]

Comment: It's not like the class keyword is illegal as he uses it, though. The following is a perfectly valid TU: `void f(class foo);`. If "foo" is not yet known, it will be introduced there, so it's a forward declaration at an uncommon place though.

Comment: @litb: 100% correct, but probably more confusing than helpful for a beginner. I've had some experience with C++ but I'd be doing a double or triple take if I came across `void f(class foo);` in the wild.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the extended explanation. Much appreciated!

Comment: I am not a C++ programmer, but the topic is interesting, in an example on Wikipedia I saw this: __void insert(Node*& root, int data)__ What does it mean? Pass a reference to a pointer that points to a Node type of object. Isn't __void insert(Node* root, int data)__ in fact the same declaration? What is the difference, if there is, between the two?

Comment: @tonix probably little late to the party but for any others who stumble upon this Node*& means a reference to the pointer to a Node instance as opposed to Node* which is just a pointer to a Node instance. In the first case the value of the pointer is passed by reference and can be changed in the function. In the second case you are only able to change the Node instance. If you want to modify the pointer the caller passed to your function you need the first declaration.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to pass class *instances* (objects), you either use

```
 void function(const MyClass& object){
   // do something with object  
 }
```

or

```
 void process(MyClass& object_to_be_changed){
   // change member variables  
 }
```

On the other hand if you want to "pass" the *class* itself

```
template<class AnyClass>
void function_taking_class(){
   // use static functions of AnyClass
   AnyClass::count_instances();
   // or create an object of AnyClass and use it
   AnyClass object;
   object.member = value;
}
// call it as 
function_taking_class<MyClass>();
// or 
function_taking_class<MyStruct>();
```

with

```
class MyClass{
  int member;
  //...
};
MyClass object1;
```

Answer (score 12):

At its simplest:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
   public:
     A( int x ) : n( x ){}
     void print() { cout << n << endl; }
   private:
     int n;
};

void func( A p ) {
   p.print();
}

int main () {
   A a;
   func ( a );
}
```

Of course, you should probably be using references to pass the object, but I suspect you haven't got to them yet.

Comment: Pass by ref is a necessary quirk of C++ that *needs* to be introduced up front, even if the user doesn’t understand it yet. In particular, the OP wanted to *modify* the class members.

Comment: If he doesn't understand how to make a simple function call, I think introducing references is a bad idea. And if he wants to change the contents of the class, he also needs to understand private & public and constness.

Comment: You have to pass some value when you create an object as in A a(4); in line number 3 from down, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I was asking the same too. Another solution is you could overload your method:

```
void remove_id(EmployeeClass);
void remove_id(ProductClass);
void remove_id(DepartmentClass);
```

in the call the argument will fit accordingly the object you pass. but then you will have to repeat yourself

```
void remove_id(EmployeeClass _obj) {
    int saveId = _obj->id;
    ...
};

void remove_id(ProductClass _obj) {
    int saveId = _obj->id;
    ...
};

void remove_id(DepartmentClass _obj) {
    int saveId = _obj->id;
    ...
};
```

Answer (score -3):

holy errors The reason for the code below is to show how to not void main every function and not to type return; for functions...... instead push everything into the sediment for which is the print function prototype... if you need to use useful functions ... you will have to below.....
*(p.s. this below is for people overwhelmed by these object and T templates which allow different variable declaration types(such as float and char) to use the same passed by value in a user defined function)*

```
char arr[ ] = "This is a test";

string str(arr);


//  You can also assign directly to a string.
str = "This is another string";
```

can anyone tell me why c++ made arrays into pass by value one at a time and the only way to eliminate spaces and punctuation is the use of string tokens. I couldn't get around the problem when i was trying to delete spaces for a palindrome...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int getgrades(float[]);
int getaverage(float[], float);
int calculateletters(float[], float, float, float[]);
int printResults(float[], float, float, float[]);


int main()
{

int i;
float  maxSize=3, size;
float  lettergrades[5], numericgrades[100], average;

size=getgrades(numericgrades);
average = getaverage(numericgrades, size);
printResults(numericgrades, size, average, lettergrades);
return 0;
}

int getgrades(float a[])
{ 


int i, max=3;

for (i = 0; i <max; i++)
{
    //ask use for input
    cout << "\nPlease Enter grade " << i+1 << " : ";
    cin >> a[i];
    //makes sure that user enters a vlue between 0 and 100

   if(a[i] < 0 || a[i] >100)
    {
        cout << "Wrong input. Please
 enter a value between 0 and 100 only." << endl;
        cout << "\nPlease Reenter grade " << i+1 << " : ";
        cin >> a[i];

        return i;
    }
}
}

int getaverage(float a[], float n) 
{ 
int i;
float sum = 0;
 if (n == 0)
return 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
sum += a[i];
return sum / n;
}                               


int printResults(float a[], float n, float average, float letters[]) 
{
int i;
cout << "Index Number | input  |
array values address in memory " << endl;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
cout <<"     "<< i<<" \t\t"<<setprecision(3)<<
a[i]<<"\t\t" << &a[i] << endl;
}
cout<<"The average of your grades is: "<<setprecision(3)<<average<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.