# C++ and class object names

Tags: c++, class, variables, parameter-passing

when I have a class and I'm making an object of this class, ex:

```
    class Sample{
    ...
    };

    int main(){ Sample object1; ...}
```

Is the name of the object just a address to it? When I'm sending class object name as argument to a function recursively I'm just sending the address not copying the whole object in memory?

Comment: No, unless the parameter to the function is a reference `(Sample& obj)` or a pointer `(Sample* ptr)` you're invoking copy construction with each invoke of the recursion. At each call the original remains unchanged.

Comment: @Vilo: There's no recursion in your [invalid] code up there.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit there I go again answering a question without reading the code (that doesn't match =P)

Comment: @WhozCraig: Your comment isn't wrong

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah, but as you pointed out the question/code relation sure is whacked.

Comment: This is only a sample code to show you what I mean by "class object name".
I'm making another recursive function that uses data from stl's list that are on another class.
Every run of function should have access to the same lists as the one that started it, so I'm sending every time the class object with those lists set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A name is not an address but a name. It exists in your source code and at compilation, but otherwise not at all (sort of). It is a semantic construct, not a value in memory.

The rules of what happens to an object whose name you're using in your code can be found in your C++ book. In general, *copies* are performed by default — to avoid copies you pass by reference, or pass a pointer to an object.

Comment: I mentioned name like with arrays, when I create the array SampleArray[10] it's name SampleArray used as argument sends the memory address to the SampleArray[0].

So for "Sample object1;" I have to start the function with function(&object1); and execute it with function(Sample* object2){} ?

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896369/how-to-use-a-class-object-in-c-as-a-function-parameter ?

Comment: @Vilo: that's because an array expression can be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element, when used in most contexts (e.g. in your example because you can't pass an array). However, the array variable still represents the whole array.